# How to put part of a string on a newline based on a given number? (Ignoring the spaces)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
T = 7
string = "this is a string"
```

How do I put a part of the string on a new line, after 7 "lengths"? **Also I don't want to include spaces as a character.**
It should print out:

```
this is a  < -- length = 7 (You don't need to print the < -- length = 7, it's just giving detail)
string  <-- The rest of the lines should not go over 7 characters, and should not break part words
that is 
very 
cool
```

I was thinking of using a `while` loop:

```
while len(string)>T:
    # keep cutting off by 7`
```

Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow, so please excuse the way my question is formatted/written for now.

Comment: Just to clarify, I use python3

Comment: Maybe slicing could help in a way as well

Comment: What happened to the space in the second line? In your example should the second line be `a strin` or `a stri` starting with a space?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of methods to do this. Incrementing a cursor position is one:

```
text = "this is a very long string to prove it actually works"
cursor = 0
T = 7
while cursor < len(text):
    print (text[cursor:cursor+T])
    cursor += T
```

As you apparently want to ignore counting spaces, though, a straight text slice cannot 
process that anymore and you will have to count each separate (printing) character. If you don't want to *start* printing a space, it also needs an additional check if printing 7 characters did not end up on a space itself.

```
T = 7
cursor = 0
while cursor < len(text):
    count_non_space = 0
    while count_non_space < T and cursor < len(text):
        print (text[cursor],end='')
        count_non_space += not(text[cursor].isspace())
        cursor += 1
    while cursor < len(text) and text[cursor] == ' ':
        print (text[cursor],end='')
        cursor += 1
    print ()
```

which results in

```
this is a 
very lon
g string 
to prove 
it actua
lly work
s
```

By the way, do not use the name [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html) for a variable.

Comment: thank you very much, but do you know how to ignore the spaces as characters?

Answer (score 1):

All other solutions I've tried got awkward the moment I started handling the spaces "properly", so I present: [a regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/FWPOjB/2)!

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doggie"
>>> pattern = r"\S(?:\s*\S){6}|(?:\S\s*){,6}$"
>>> for match in re.findall(pattern, string):
...     print(match)
the quic
k brown f
ox jumps
over the
lazy dog
gie
```

We only count non-spaces as characters (meaning our strings are typically longer than 7 characters), and spaces are effectively stripped from the edges of the matches.

Here's how the pattern works:

```
\S(?:\s*\S){6}|(?:\S\s*){,6}$    Match either:
\S                               - a non-space character
  (       ){6}                     followed by six times:
   ?:                              (non-capturing)
     \s*\S                         any amount of spaces, and _one_ non-space
              |                  OR
               (?:     ){,6}     - _up to_ six times:
                  \S\s*            a non-space and any amount of spaces,
                            $      but only if we're at the end of the string
```

Comment: This is brilliant! @L3viathan

Comment: How about `r"\S(?:\s*\S){,6}"`?

Comment: @L3viathan Wow this is really good! But is it possible that we don't break apart any words? The ideal code would be that the first line has 7 characters, and the rest of the lines do not go over 7 characters, and don't break apart any word's in the process.

Comment: @Sar17 So are you [Joyce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796604/group-elements-in-a-list-based-on-its-length) after all?

Comment: @Sar17 You changed the question since I answered this. Maybe look into [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I first split the string. Then I check for each word if that would exceed the 7 character limit `T` if so, add a newline before adding that word to the output. If not, add a space (except for the first word, as we don't want the output to start with a space. That should do it.

```
mystring = "this is a string"

substrings=mystring.split()

T = 7
i = 0
charCount = 0
output=""

print substrings

while(i < len(substrings)):
    charCount += len(substrings[i])
    if(charCount > T):
        output+="\n"
    elif(i != 0):
        output+=" "

    output+=substrings[i]
    i += 1

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

For another method, you can use a for loop with modulo 7

```
a = "..."
for i in range(len(a) // 7):
    print(a[7*i:7*i+7])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actualy pretty easy:

```
string = "this is a string"
newString = string[:7]+"\n"+string[7:]
```

`string[:7]` is the string up to but not including the seventh character
'"\n"`is the newline character`
string[7:]` is the string from the seventh character to the end.

Read about "slices" on strings.

Comment: thank you very much, but do you know how I can ignore spaces as a character?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension to split `string` into a list of strings.

```py
string_ = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog'
T = 7
list_of_strings = [string_[T*i : T*(i+1)] for i in range(int(len(string_)/T + 1))]

for new_string in list_of_strings:
    print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
The Qui
ck Brow
n Fox J
umps Ov
er the 
Lazy Do
g
```

If you want to exclude gaps, use the `.replace` method to remove gaps.

```py
string_ = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog'
string_nogaps = string_.replace(' ', '')
T = 7
list_of_strings = [string_nogaps[T*i : T*(i+1)] for i in range(int(len(string_nogaps)/T + 1))]

for new_string in list_of_strings:
    print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
TheQuic
kBrownF
oxJumps
Overthe
LazyDog
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you know how i can ignore the spaces as characters? So in your example it would be:  The Quic  (\n) k Brown F (\n)  ox Jumps (\n) Over the (\n) Lazy Dog